# Can Hosting affect a plugin from working properly?

Tags: plugins, updates

I have developed a website for a client, I built it on my own hosting account so it would not affect their current site.  I have since transferred all of the data to the new site. However one of the plugins will not allow me to save changes on the "live" site.  Everything is the same between the test site and the live site besides the hosting accounts, same wordpress versions, all plugins are up to date and the same on both. I have contacted the plugin developer and they told me to deactivate all of the plugins to see if one of the current plugins is causing it not to work.  If this was the case wouldn't I be having the same issue on the test site?

Any thoughts on this would be helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, sure. Differences in the PHP and MySQL versions could certainly lead to different behavior. How likely it is that it only shows in settings not being saved, that is another question.

Do you get any messages in the browser's console? Any Ajax requests ending in errors in the Network tab?

Is there anything in the error log on the server? Have you tested with [WP_DEBUG](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)?

You could also hook into wpdb's `query` to debug which statements are actually sent to the database.

Comment: I found a console error > Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (forbidden)

Comment: For what request? That might explain it, might also be completely unrelated.

Comment: I made a change within the plugin and while it is trying to save I clicked inspect and went to console and that is there error is shows, I guess I am not sure where the exact request shows. When I click onto Network it does not show any Ajax errors.

Comment: Keep the network tab open, then click "save". Make sure to have "preserve log" checked if you're using chrome, otherwise the log will be reset if you browse to another page or refresh this one.

Comment: the error name in the network tab was admin.php?page=plugin-admin-general-settings